# Laravel 7 Auth::login from an Event listener

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to integrate SAML login with Laravel session.
After a successful SAML login the user is redirected to the laravel app where a SamlLogin event is fired passing the user information.
I've an event listener for the SamlLogin where I am trying to match the user from SAML with the user from the local database and then manually authenticate him using Auth::login().
After the manual authentication the user is redirected to the Home controller
In the event listener the user is authenticated successfully

But when I try to get the user in the Homecontroller with Auth::user() there is no available user in the session.

What am I missing? Should I explicitly use web guard or refer to the session in any way both in the listener or the controller?

Here is the event handler

```
public function handle(SamlLogin $event)
{
    /* @var \SimplerSaml\User */
    $samlUser = $event->user;

    $user = User::firstOrCreate([
        'email' => $samlUser['email']
    ], [
        'name' => $samlUser['name'],
    ]);

    Auth::login($user, true);
    redirect()->route('home');
}
```

And this is the controller method

```
   public function index()
{
    $userName = Auth::user()->name;
    return view('home');
}
```

where I got the error: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Comment: What do you get if you `dd ($user['name'])` right after firstOrCreate method? If you get `null` somethings wrong with your method.

Comment: I got the name correctly, the user is loaded/created in the event listener without any issue

Answer (score 0):

try Auth::loginUseingId($user->id) in handler function

Comment: No changes, same error, the user session is lost between the listener and the controller